# To get a friendlist

Tags: javascript, facebook

By using

me?fields=first_name,friends

I'm getting the count of friends but not the name and details of a friend. pls help me out on how to get details of friends in facebook app. I'm using version 2.4 of graph api--may be this info help you to answer my question. I need a invite friens pop up. Please respond

Comment: you might want to provide much more information including the code you have issues with

Comment: I'm getting the count of friends but not the user name of my friend list' here is the code which is showing count

{
  "friends": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 3
    }
  },
  "id": "1398857323742641",
}


It is just giving the count and even though I have taken all the permissions but still I was unable to see the friendslist

Answer (score 1):

Since v2.0 of the Graph API, you can only get friends who authorized your App with the `user_friends` permission too.

Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

Btw, how to invite friends to your App is explained in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite